# Using CDK and Ncurses under Microsoft Windows

Tags: c, windows, ncurses, ncurses-cdk

I wrote a program in C that uses the CDK to create an user interface. It works great under Linux, but some people under Windows need it.

I've heard that Cygwin could help me, so last 3 days I was trying to recompile my program with the help of Cygwin. I tried a lot of things, like differents compilers, recompile nCurses from source, recompile CDK from source, using PDCurses... but I always failed. I got many types of problems and errors so I just can't list that here...

Is there a solution to use the CDK library under Windows ?

Comment: CDK's never been ported to use PDCurses (just Unix curses and ncurses).  You can install an ncurses development package in Cygwin, which should help.

Comment: With the ncurses package it does compile and it works within the Cygwin environment. But when running the .exe outside I got the error "Error opening terminal: cygwin"

Comment: If they're running Windows 10, they can try using your software on [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).